# Meaning of * character in a struct.pack line?

Tags: python-2.7, struct.pack

Can anyone tell me what the * character is doing in this line of python code?

```
struct.pack(">%df" % numframes, *[frame/fps for frame in xrange(numframes)])
```

I've look through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) but I can't find that character on it's own.

Thanks!

Comment: The list comprehension generates a series of values, and `*` applies those as separate arguments to the `struct.pack()` call.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check out the dupe link as well.